# Como posso acessar um setor do hd

Tags: c

Gostaria de saber como posso fazer um código para manipular um setor do HD e fazer um teste nele como o HDD regeneration faz por exemplo. E quais bibliotecas utilizo no C ? (não sei se no HD é ponteiro tmb por isso estou chamando de setor, perdoem a minha ignorância).

Na teoria seria, pegar alguns dados, gravar no setor, ler o setor, copiar o dado para outro setor e apagar o dado do setor ??

desde já, obrigado!

Comment: O que você já tentou fazer?

Comment: ainda nada, só queria ter uma dica para como começar !!!

Comment: Do jeito que está sua pergunta vai ser fechada como fora do escopo. Se você colocar pedindo dicas sobre como começar, ela vai ser fechada como baseada em opinião. Veja essa parte: [Como fazer uma boa pergunta?](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: entendi, obg msm assim, vou ver se consigo descobrir então como faço!!!

Answer (score 2):

Você não faz.
Não como um programa que funciona no nível de usuário: O sistema operacional não permite que programas (em contraste com drivers de dispositivo) tenham acesso ao hardware - mas permite acesso a camadas  abstraídas dele.

ENtão - no mínimo dos mínimos, você tem que dizer em qual sistema operacional está trabalhando: WIndows, Linux, Mac OS X ou outro - e fazer código para funcionar dentro dele.

**Windows**
No tempo do DOS e dos primeiros Windows - que não conseguiam impedir que os programas fizessem acesso direto ao Hardware - talvez até o XP, senão até o ME - você poderia ter acesso "físico" ao disco chamando funções da BIOS diretamente - a "int 13h" -  Essas "int"s, ou interrupções, tratam eventos de hardware, mas também eram uma forma de chamar uma API - como se fosse uma biblioteca - direto na BIOS para acesso ao Hardware.

Para acessar uma rotina do tipo "ler um setor", o seu código tinha que carregar os parâmetros para a chamada em registradores específicos da CPU,e então executar a instrução de máquina "int 13h" - a BIOS executava a rotina - lia os dados, e os transferia para a areade memoria especificada nos registradores.

COmo isso depende dos valores exatos nos registradores, em gera codificado em Assembler mesmo - no máximo como código assembler Inline dentro de uma função C. Os compiladores sempre davam uma alternativa ou outra para escrever código que precisasse fazer isso.

Hoje em dia, *se* você tiver um PC que permtia colcaor uma BIOS legada, e um drive de diskettes, é possível que possa escrever código assembler chamando diretamente essa rotina, e colocar no setor de boot do diskette. - Os PCs cotiuam sendo compatíveis com os PCs daquela época: você vai escrever assembler 16 bits (isso - seu i5 de 8a geração, com 8mb de cache L1, quando é ligado, acorda achando que é um 8086 com 1MB de memória no máximo - e são necessárias instruções de máquina especiais para irem mudnado os modos de operação da CPU. Bom - pode ser que com os sistemas UEFI atuais isso não seja mais verdade -  mas, se o seu boot for BIOS, sim, é isso).

Na falta de um drive de diskettes, você pode tentar o mesmo approah usando o [DOSBOX](http://www.dosbox.com/), e efetivamente programando uma máquina virtual no sistema DOS  - vai ser o melhor jeito de voce conseguir fazer o que quer.

(Olha - eu pesquisei por BIOS int 13 disk access para ver se achava informação bem estruturada de como isso funciona - mas, más notícias - tudo fragmentado, e nada que "coemce do começo" para mostrar como você pode fazer isso desde o começo (com os compialdores, etc...)- mesmo num ambiente de DOS emulado). Aqui talvez pelo menos tem a API da int13h mais documentada: http://stanislavs.org/helppc/int_13.html

Para acessar drives da "idade dos 32bits" talvez seja possível usar uma API do Windows diretamente - mas, vai ser ladeira acima: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/100027

**Linux** eo outros Unixes:
Esses sistemas expõem os dispositivos de disco como se fossem "um arquivão gigante" - um único arquivo com todo o tamanho do disco.

Então, como usuário *root*, e as chamadas normais de leitura, seek e escrita em arquivos, você move coisas diretas no disco. Isso abstrai todaa parte de cálculo de setores, etc... Mas..desde os tempos dos HDs de 512MB, alguma parte do Hardware já abstrai isso pra você de qualquer forma. (Por isso nem me ocorreu dar essa explicação primeiro ao responder sua pergunta - e sai falando de "como era" )

Se quiser por exemplo, ver o setor de boot do seu HD num Linux, basta ver os priemeiros 512 bytes do arquivo /dev/sda  -
Você pode usar um pendrive - ele aparece como dispositivo de bloco /dev/sdb  - se você escrever um porgrama que seja código de máquina válido em assembler 8086 (16bit) e copiar para os primeiros 512 bytes desse dispositivo, ao bootar pelo pendrive, (desligando boot UEFI, etc...)  - vai poder ver seu programa rodando.

E por fim  - quanto a essa parte da sua pergunta:

> Na teoria seria, pegar alguns dados, gravar no setor, ler o setor, copiar o dado para outro setor e apagar o dado do setor ??

COm o acesso a disco como "dispositvo de blocos" no Unix você pode fazer isso - mas se fizer, a chance é que você destrua a informação contida nos arquivos do disco - por que você tem que respeitar as estruturas de dados do sistema de arquivos que está no disco.

De novo, o sistema de arquivos usado no tempo do DOS é a FAT -e ainda é usada até hoje em pendrives, cartões de memoria, etc... é um dos mais simples, e um dos  únicos em que é possível fazer um progrma independente apra acesso aos dados sem usar o próprio código do sistema de arquivos em si.

Comment: Muitíssimo obrigado Sr. jsbueno, me ajudou muito !!!! :D

Comment: Essas funções da BIOS  sobres as Essas "int"s 13,1 e 13,4, fazem exatamente o que preciso muito obrigado. agora acho q com alguns simples contadores e uns Algoritmo de ordenação consigo resolver meu problema !! Muito obrigado msm !!! ^_^

Comment: @MatheusChagas se a resposta resolveu seu problema, você pode clicar no **V** ao lado da resposta e marcar sua pergunta como respondida